# Rails - better way to create multiple modals in large table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, modal-dialog, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-modal

I used 2 for loops to create a 10x50 table. Each table cell has a link that will open a modal to submit a form. The kicker here is that I need to pass attributes from each table cell link to the modal so that it conveniently pre-populates the modal form for a better user experience. I have this all working properly but the view page takes a long time (sometimes >10 seconds) to load because it is generating 500 modals every page load. Does anyone any ideas to better design this?

Is there a way to pass the unique link attributes to the modal directly based on what the user clicks, and just load 1 modal outside of the 2 for loops? Ultimately, I need the 'hour' and 'room' attribute accessible in the modal so I can prepopulate the form in the modal. I can't quite seem to figure out this option.

Hope someone out there has some advice. TIA! Code below.

```
<% (0..49).each do |hour| %>
  <tr class="center">
    <td></td>
    <% (1..10).each do |room| %>
       <td>
          <%= link_to "Book", "#", data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#bookingModal-#{hour}-#{room}"} %>
          # Modal Code here
       </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: If you want to do so, it needs to separate modal code to a partial, then using ajax remote request when clicking to link open modal to render modal with the right parameter

Comment: @QuânHoàng...code in a comment like this would be more useful if given as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to build multiple modals. Just build one and in the link to open modal you can add more data.
For example:

```
<%= link_to "Book", "#", data: {toggle: "modal", hour: "{hour}", room: "{room}"}, class: 'booking-button'  %>
```

Then use jquery to set data value to the modal:
For example:

```
$('.booking-button').on('click', function(){
   let hour = $(this).data('hour'); // Set to modal input
   let room = $(this).data('room'); // Set to modal input
   $('#booking-modal').modal('open'); // Open modal
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a remote link to a rails action with a js view that launches the modal.
E.g.

```
<%= link_to "Book", modal_books_path(hour, room), remote: true %>
```

```
class BooksController
  def modal
    format.js
  end
end
```

```
resources :books do
  get 'modal/:hour/:room', on: :collection
end
```

```js
// app/views/books/modal.js
$("<%= render 'modal', hour: params[:hour], room: params[:room] %>").appendTo("body");
$('#booking-modal').modal('show');
// Remove your html on close.
```

```html
<!-- app/views/books/_modal.html.erb -->
<!-- Your modal html goes here -->
```

More info about working with rails and JS: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html